# How to handle cookie in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, cookies, session-cookies, hybrid-mobile-app, setcookie

I'm developing a Hybrid mobile app and i'm new at this. As part of project , there is cookie in headers which authenticates my service calls at server. Now im facing issue in clearing the cookie or headers on clicking logout option. Due to this App gets logged even without entering credentials.Please help me out with possible ways of handling this situation.[image: Headers list]

I need to handle the Set-Cookie parameter.Please let me know if any information required.I'm totally new at this , so ignore if there is any information missed.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, server should return Set-Cookie: %auth_key%:null after logout action, but you can unset cookies manually via $cookies provider from ngCookies module.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service

```
angular.module('cookiesExample', ['ngCookies'])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$cookies', function($cookies) {
  // Retrieving a cookie
  var favoriteCookie = $cookies.get('myFavorite');
  // Setting a cookie
  $cookies.put('myFavorite', 'oatmeal');
  // Removing a cookie
  $cookies.remove('your_auth_key');
}]);
```

**EDIT:**

```
var commonHeaderModule = angular.module('commonHeaderModule', ['ngCookies']);

commonHeaderModule.controller('commonHeaderController', ['$scope', '$cookies', '$lo‌​cation', '$rootScope'‌​,
    function($scope, $cookies, $location, $rootScope) {
        $(document).on('click', function() {
            $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
        });
        $scope.logout = function() {
            $cookies.remove('Cookie');
            alert("done");
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: I don't have logout service , so need to handle manually. I have tried the above approach but its throwing error. below is my code.                                          var commonHeaderModule = angular.module('commonHeaderModule',['ngCookies']);
commonHeaderModule.controller('commonHeaderController',['$scope','$cookies','$location','$rootScope',function($scope,$cookies,$location,$rootScope){

 $(document).on('click',function(){
  $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
 }) 

 $scope.logout = function(){
    $cookies.remove('Cookie');
    alert("done");
 }


}]);

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at k.$scope.logout (file:///android_asset/www/js/modules/commonHeaderController.js:9:14)
    at file:///android_asset/www/lib/js/angular.min.js:176:387
    at file:///android_asset/www/lib/js/angular.min.js:193:521
    at k.$eval (file:///android_asset/www/lib/js/angular.min.js:112:15)

Comment: Did you actually installed ngCookies? This is a separate module, you can install it via bower ( bower install angular-cookies ) or download manually ( https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/ ).

Comment: Yes, i have installed it.

Comment: Can you copy-paste the code I've posted in edit section above and check if it helps? Looks like $co‌​okies and $rootScope variables have unseen symbols (or same-looking non-latin letters). Also please check other dependencies to be imported in the same charset.

Comment: var commonHeaderModule = angular.module('commonHeaderModule',['ngCookies']);
commonHeaderModule.controller('commonHeaderController',['$scope','$cookies','$window',function($scope,$cookies,$window){

 $(document).on('click',function(){
  $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
 })

 $scope.logout = function(){
        $cookies.get('Cookie');
      $cookies.remove('Cookie');
    alert("done");


 }


}]);

Comment: I have replaced as given but getting error again.TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at k.$scope.logout (file:///android_asset/www/js/modules/commonHeaderController.js:9:18)
    at file:///android_asset/www/lib/js/angular.min.js:176:387
    at file:///android_asset/www/lib/js/angular.min.js:193:521
    at k.$eval (file:///android_asset/www/lib/js/angular.min.js:112:15)

Comment: Try this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/ERJMdzrJR7Yg1e7f4uor?p=preview . I've made basic remove-all function for cookies with ngCookie.

Comment: var commonHeaderModule = angular.module('commonHeaderModule', ['ngCookies']);

commonHeaderModule.controller('commonHeaderController', ['$scope', '$cookies', '$window',
    function($scope, $cookies, $window) {
        //$(document).on('click', function() {
        //    $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
        //});
        $scope.logout = function() {
            //this will give all cookies to you
            var cookies = $cookies.getAll();
            console.log(cookies);

Comment: im getting null for cookies